# Access different type of preset target location in Luigi

Tags: apache-spark, luigi, hail

I have a `luigi` pipeline. There is a file where `Google Cloud` is set as a target location:

https://github.com/macarthur-lab/hail-elasticsearch-pipelines/blob/d6e9dedbce929c04c294c54095663ba94a4de3f0/luigi_pipeline/lib/hail_tasks.py#L37

Now, there is `run_vep()` method that calls other ones ultimately ending up calling the following, different `run_vep()`:

https://github.com/macarthur-lab/hail-elasticsearch-pipelines/blob/d6e9dedbce929c04c294c54095663ba94a4de3f0/hail_scripts/v02/utils/hail_utils.py#L103

There we are using `Google Cloud` path to access the files, but I want now to access local files instead. Is there a way to change where `luigi` looks for files temporarily? The thing is that I have two locations for where `luigi` should get the files and need both of them to be accessible instead of just one or the other. How could this issue be handled in `luigi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that their function `hl.vep()` actually expects `config` that should have local paths and not `hadoop` ones. After specifying the local paths, things worked for me. Still it would be interesting to know how to access this or that file system directly for which source code of `hl.vep()` may be useful too.